# Rails API - Local file is not uploading to s3/Heroku

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, fog

These are the parameters that are being passed to my HTTP POST request, as so:

```
Parameters: {
"vision"=>{
  "description"=>"dsfsfdsfdsfsd",
  "image"=>"file:///Users/ozgecokyasar/Library/Developer/
     CoreSimulator/Devices/EDD6C498-DACD-433E-B96D-3A30BAE7BA6D/data/
     Containers/Data/Application/
     6F633096-E665-46BB-952F-2775DD85A4A6/Library/Caches/
     ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fmanifestation-react- 
     3ac1cbe2-549f-
     49e7-8506-ef29638d1643/ImagePicker/0E426602-8110-4A9C-8B9A- 
     96D0BF1B2ECE.jpg"
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, it saves as so (image is nil):

```
SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "visions" ("image", "description", "created_at",
 "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" 
 [["image", nil], ["description", "dsfsfdsfdsfsd"], ["created_at", "2019-
01-12 01:14:34.341356"],["updated_at", "2019-01-12 01:14:34.341356"], 
["user_id", 3]]
```

Why is the image column nil?

**visions_controller.rb:**

```
  def create
    @vision = current_user&.visions.build(vision_params)
    @vision.remote_image_url = params[:image]

    @vision.save
    render :create, status: :created
  end
```

**vision model:**

```
class Vision < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

However, I am able to successfully save remote URLs into my image column if I change my create action in visions_controller to:

```
  def create
    @vision = current_user&.visions.build(vision_params)
    @vision.remote_image_url = 'ANY REMOTE IMAGE URL'

    @vision.save
    render :create, status: :created
  end
```

Why is it that when I add params[:image], the image param being passed gets saved as nil?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `params[:vision][:image]`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma
I changed it to `@vision.remote_image_url = params[:vision][:image]`
However, I get the following response:



`{"data":{"user":{"id":null,"image":{"url":null,"thumb":{"url":null},"small":{"url":null},"large":{"url":null},"medium":{"url":null}},"description":"dsfsfdsfdsfsd"}}}`



The parameters were sent like this:
`{"vision"=>{"description"=>"dsfsfdsfdsfsd", "image"=>"file:///Users/ozgecokyasar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDD6C498-DACD-433E-B96D/data/Containers/Data/Application/2775DA4A6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%.jpg"}}`

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: @SebastianPalma the above gives me the following error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Image trying to download a file which is not served over HTTP):`. So why am I not able to upload a local files to S3 but remote URLs are uploaded perfectly fine?

Comment: The error is being clear, `file:///Users/ozgecokyasar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDD6C498-DACD-433E-B96D/data/Containers/Data/Application/2775DA4A6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%.jpg"`, this points to a local file which haven't been stored anywhere.

Comment: so do I have to temporarily store it or cache it and upload to S3 from the temporary directory? Can you please explain? lol sorry I'm a noob @SebastianPalma

Comment: Yes, you need, I forgot to ask, but it's supposed you should be using something like Carrierwave, Paperclip or ActiveStorage, the file should be "retrievable" by being saved in somewhere, your home folder isn't accessible from outside your own laptop (by now).

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks, I'm using CarrierWave and Fog. Where am I supposed to save the file before I attempt to upload it to s3?

Comment: If working with S3 you should add in the configuration your S3 credentials, and depending how's configured, to work in a "local" storage or S3 depending your current environment.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I opened a new question :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172570/how-can-i-temporarily-store-cache-images-before-uploading-to-s3